# Auto Blacklisting in Postfix

Tags: security, postfix, ipv6, smtp

I have numerous Postfix directives which successfully limit abuse. **HOWEVER**: After a restriction is enforced, the abuser just reconnects and goes through the complete process of re-failing the same tests. There is no persistence of memory in regards to previous restrictions a connecting client has had enforced.

Is there any solution to short-circuit this loop and go straight to a block after an resource-expensive directive has been enforced just once? Ideally I'd like support for blacklisting both IPv4 / IPv6 addresses-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE:

I've made a material update to the solution and added IPv6 support and housekeeping to implement a "rolling" block list to prune IPs after offenders stop hitting your server.

### Intro:

**Although there are many Postfix directives which can block abusers, the problem with these is there's no persistence of memory of such previous decisions.** So an abuser can endlessly reconnect and their traffic has to re-failed by the same tests. The ultimate goal therefore is to break this endless loop of abuse and just ban an offending IP after the first resource-intensive test has been failed.

I've [opensourced a solution](https://github.com/f1linux/postfix-autoBlacklisting) I run on my own (somewhat) busy mailserver which is hosting many accounts for many domains. In a nutshell it creates a SystemD Service & Timer which fires a script which uses RegExs to scrape `/var/log/maillog` for abuse patterns- for both IPv4 & IPv6 addresses. Testing has so far been successful reducing abuse substantially.

Specimen output from `/etc/postfix/access`. Not the inclusion of a single IPv6 address:

```
213.230.115.33 REJECT
213.230.75.114 REJECT
185.66.252.78 REJECT
162.243.133.39 REJECT
104.168.159.38 REJECT
78.128.113.109 REJECT
77.40.3.227 REJECT
77.40.3.101 REJECT
61.163.192.88 REJECT
37.0.20.10 REJECT
26.189.237.221 REJECT
[2001:da8:5066:66:eda:41ff:fe1d:b27] REJECT
```

BTW, getting IPv6 to work with this was a bit of a monkey, but I got there in the end ;-)

### Blacklisting Strategy:

**In 2.5 months I had about 1200+ IPs blacklisted** using the previous iteration of my repo which persistently recorded offender IPs. Without a mechanism to periodically prune this list there would be scalability issues. My new approach is to create a rolling block list: continuously scrape the maillog for new abuser IPs and drop those no longer appearing in the maillog. **Any other approach I could think of was based on an arbitrary amount of time to purge IPs.**

So after a log rotation if an abuser doesn't appear in the new maillog, they will NOT be included in the blacklist- only if they make a subsequent abuse attempt. IPs are there blacklisted only for the life of maillog before a rotation.

### Code

I can say that the repo does what it says on the tin from my testing.  However, I don't doubt that some parts could be more elegant. Below is the main script that does the business and offered for peer review.

If you have any thoughts/suggestions, let's hear them or better still send me a pull request (please only after you've tested your enhancements).  The script is easy to test- *it does everything for you and all the code is well commented*- and equally easy to unwind.

**PLEASE NOTE**: This script only has effect if you have directives which read the "access" map in `main.cf`. [Also note that Postfix's restrictive directives are enforced left-to-right](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html), so any directive reading the "access" map should be left of directives that run more expensive tests.

The repo includes a script to uninstall everything if you just want to do some testing.

```
cat <<'EOF'> /etc/postfix/access-autoBlacklisting.sh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Author/Developer: Terrence Houlahan Linux Engineer F1Linux.com
# Linkedin: https://www.linkedin.com/in/terrencehoulahan
# License: GPL 3.0
# Source:  https://github.com/f1linux/postfix-autoBlacklisting.git
# Version: 03.20.00

# OPERATION:
# ----------
# This script PREPENDS offending IP addresses from "/var/log/maillog" to "/etc/postfix/access"
# This ensures restrictive access rules applied before permissive grants.
# Consult README.md file for more granular detail about this script and its operation.

# Stop timer from executing Blacklisting script: Existing blacklist in /etc/postfix/access is enforce enforced while the new blacklist rebuilds
systemctl stop Postfix-AutoBlacklisting.timer

# Purge blacklist: Blacklist recreated each script execution capturing both previous offending IPs as well as newest ones present in logs
sed -i '/REJECT$/d' /etc/postfix/access

# Purge the scratch file:
> /etc/postfix/access-blacklist

### Scrape log for different forms of abuse using different tests to identify abuse IPs and squirt each to same central file:
# Enable/Disable any of below tests according to your requirements. Adding your own is easy if you use my tests which isolate offending IPs as templates.

# TEST 1: Blacklist Zombie hosts from endlessly squirting spam: These are identified by no PTR record being set for them.
# This test will catch both new zombies as well as those already RBLed which should serve to stop them constantly being endlessly checked against the RBL
# IPv4 Test:
# Below commented test was found to not be 100 perecent as accurate as the one using the awk form. Have not investigated why however.
#grep "does not resolve to address" /var/log/maillog | grep -Eo "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | sort -u >> /etc/postfix/access-blacklist
grep "does not resolve to address" /var/log/maillog | awk 'match($0, /([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}/) {print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' | sort -u >> /etc/postfix/access-blacklist
# IPv6 Test:
grep "does not resolve to address" /var/log/maillog | grep -Eo "2[0-9a-fA-F]{3}:(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}[:]{1,2}){1,6}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})" | sort -u | awk '{print "["$1"]"}' >> /etc/postfix/access-blacklist


# TEST 2: Block spammers guessing account names where they know our domain:
# WARNING: this could potentially cause a block where an unintentional misspelling of an mail account name occured.
# Uncomment only if you are OK with accepting such a risk:
# IPv4 Test:
#grep "Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table" /var/log/maillog | sed -rn 's/.*\[(([0-9]{,3}.){4})\].*/\1/gp' >> /etc/postfix/access-blacklist
# IPv6 Test:
#grep "Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table" /var/log/maillog | grep -Eo "2[0-9a-fA-F]{3}:(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}[:]{1,2}){1,6}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})" | sort -u | awk '{print "["$1"]"}' >> /etc/postfix/access-blacklist


# Populate an array with sorted and depuplicated list of offending IPs scraped from maillog using foregoing tests:
readarray arrayIPblacklist < <( cat /etc/postfix/access-blacklist | sort -u -t . -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n | sed '/^$/d' )

# If "access" is a new empty file then the subsequent "sed" will fail. Any new file will have a zero size so the '-s' test will not equal 'true'.
# So we use negation to test "true" and echo a blank space to file. The subsequent "sed" will now execute.
# If "access" file already has whitelist entry then the 'if' statement does nothing and "sed" which follows executes as expected for a non-empty file:
if [ ! -s /etc/postfix/access ]; then echo "" > /etc/postfix/access; fi

for i in "${arrayIPblacklist[@]}"; do
        # Write list of IPS from array to TOP of "access" file to enforce restrictions BEFORE processing whitelisted "OK" addresses:
        sed -i "1i $i" /etc/postfix/access
        # Append " REJECT" (with a space prepended in front of it) after each of the IPs added to to the "access" file:
        sed -i '1s/$/ REJECT/' /etc/postfix/access
done


# Rebuild the /etc/postfix/access Berkeley DB:
postmap /etc/postfix/access

systemctl reload postfix.service

# After cycle completes and IPs written to /etc/postfix/acces we wipe array which repopulates anew upon next script execution:
unset arrayIPblacklist

systemctl start Postfix-AutoBlacklisting.timer

EOF
```

### Conclusion:

I believe I've arrived as some system to maintain a persistance of memory about previously blocked IPs to stop expensive tests being endlessly repeated. Is it perfect? Probably could do with some polishing, but results seem promising from my tests so far.

If you're fed-up with your mailserver(s) being endlessly abused by the spammers, this is a quick & easy solution to implement to shut them down at the earliest opportunity:

https://github.com/f1linux/postfix-autoBlacklisting